# Why does child component do not re-render after prop change?

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I have a parent component which renders a list in a corousel (child component) from an array. When I try to re render the list on an event  only the props gets changed in the child component and not the state which do not re renders the new list in the corousel.

From the dropdown menu, I select the list to be rendered which onclick changes the props of the child component.

```
export default class DetailsInfo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showText: false,
            bannerObj:{},
            selectedid : 0,
            selectedSeason:props.item.contentType==='WebSeries'?props.item.season[0].name:'',
            seasonObj:[{
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Session 1",
                    "parts": [
                      {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "abcc",
                        "discription": null,
                        "url": "http://www.demo.com"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "abcdd",
                        "discription": null,
                        "url": "http://www.demo.com"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "abcddd",
                        "discription": null,
                        "url": "http://www.demo.com"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Session 2",
                    "parts": [
                      {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "se2ofe1",
                        "discription": null,
                        "url": "http://www.demo.com"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "se2ofe2",
                        "discription": null,
                        "url": "http://www.demo.com"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
            ]
        };
        this.handlechange = this.handlechange.bind(this);
    }

    handleOnDragStart = e => e.preventDefault()

    handlechange(event){
        const vid = this.state.seasonObj.find(o=>o.name===event.target.value).id;
        this.setState({
            selectedSeason : event.target.value,
            selectedid : vid-1
        })
    }


    render() {

        return (
            <Grid>


                <div className="maindiv">
                <div>
                        <Select onChange={this.handlechange} value={this.state.selectedSeason}>
                            {this.state.seasonObj.map(item => 
                                <MenuItem key={item.id} value={item.name} id={item.id}>{item.name}</MenuItem>
                            )}
                        </Select>
//this is were the selected id is passed to the props to child
                        {this.state.seasonObj[this.state.selectedid].id &&
                            <SliderItem item={this.state.seasonObj[this.state.selectedid].parts} />
                        }

                        </div>
                </div>
            </Grid>
        )
    }
}

// child class
export default class SliderItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            list: props.item
        }

    }

    render() {

        return (
            <React.Fragment>

                <AliceCarousel>
                    {this.state.list
                        .map((item) =>
                            <div key={item.id} >
                              <img alt={item.title} src={item.url}/>
                        </div>)}
                </AliceCarousel>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

I need to have get the courosel list updated when select from the dropdown.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use props in your AliceCarouse if you want it to be re-rendered:

```
<AliceCarousel>
  {this.props.item.map((item) => (
    <div key={item.id}>
      <img alt={item.title} src={item.url} />
    </div>
  ))}
</AliceCarousel>;
```

Comment: AliceCarousel is a react library, so will it accept other params as props ? Still I am trying...thanks

Comment: I cannot see change in the state of child component when I update the props in the parent component. Why does this happen, unable to relate to other articles as everywhere it says that when parent component changes the props the child component will get re rendered? @maksym bezruchko

Comment: In the constructor method you just initialize your state from props values. You don`t need to do that if you want your child component to be re-rendered every time when props changes. 
You can read more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html
Also if for some reason you need your state to be changed every time when props changes you can use componentDidUpdate method.

Comment: Yes when parent component changes the props child component's props. But it will not change state because props are assigned to state in constructor and to reflect the change you should set that value to state in componentWillReceiveProps

Comment: AliceCarousel also takes a "items" props which contains all the data required to slide through, passing this data through props worked!! Thanks guys!!